# What can it mean: "to eat a fist"

Tags: meaning, slang

It's from Megadeth's song : 
"They talk of days like this,
sentencing their children, 
when they need to eat a fist."

What does "to eat a fist" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a metaphor that means what it sounds like. If someone is metaphorically chewing on someone else's *fist*, it means they've been *punched* in the *face*.

However I don't think this is a particularly common (or elegant) expression, at least not in the US.  A more common (although somewhat [hackneyed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hackneyed)) expression is [*knuckle sandwich*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knuckle_sandwich).